# deriving instance Eq (Sink p)

Tags: haskell

```
class  Eq a  where
    (==), (/=)           :: a -> a -> Bool
    x /= y               = not (x == y)
    x == y               = not (x /= y)

deriving instance Eq Bool
```

I assume it generates

```
instance Eq Bool where
    True == True = True
    False == False = True
```

But how do I create a instance from something like

```
newtype Sink p = Sink {unSink :: MVar (E.Iteratee (Message p) IO ())}

instance Eq (Sink p) where
 ?==? = True
```

Do I just use deriving and ghc will figure out itself?

```
deriving instance Eq (Sink p)
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.0.0/doc/html/src/Network-WebSockets-Monad.html#Sink

PS I have read this but it goes beyond my capabilities of understanding
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html

Comment: no, I could not imagine it would work :)

Comment: After testing `newtype Sink p = Sink {unSink :: MVar (E.Iteratee (Message p) IO ())} deriving (Eq)` works because every socket has a different MVar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will work since there is an instance `Eq (MVar a)` that tests whether to `MVar`s are the same [[1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-MVar.html#MVar)]. The derived instance for `Sink` will use that. However this might not be what you want since the `Eq` instance doesn't compare the contents of the `MVar`s, only whether they are the same `MVar` in memory.

The answer to your question

> But how do I create a instance from something like ... Do I just use
>   deriving and ghc will figure out itself?

is probably "No, you must write an instance that has the properties that you want."

Comment: @GertCuykens You do some IO. But first you sit down and figure out what should happen if they don't both actually _have_ contents.

Answer (score 4):

For `Bool` the instance actually reads

```
True  == True  = True
False == False = True
_     == _     = False
```

of course.

For a description of how deriving instances works in the general case, see [Chapter 10 of the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html).

For your example type, an instance declaration equivalent to what would be derived is—straightforwardly—

```
instance Eq (Sink p) where
  Sink var == Sink var' = var == var'
```

Hence, as the type of websocket sinks is isomorphic to a certain instantiation of the type of mutable variables, comparing two sinks reduces two comparing two mutable variables.

Comment: You don't even need the `Eq p` constraint in this case.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're right. Moreover, the generated instance will not contain the constraint. I've edited my answer.